# Creating a Data Access Layer with dynamic query building capabilities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, repository-pattern, query-builder

I am using Entity Framework in my Data Access Layer and I need to support building dynamic queries through a UI (e.g. `(Name == "John" AND Age > 25).TOP(100).ORDERBY(LastName)`).

I am planning to use [`QueryBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896238%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to create the dynamic queries. For that I am thinking of creating a structure like the following:

1. A `FilterCondition` class in my Business Entities layer, which can hold conditions like `Name is equal to John`.
2. A `FilterConditionsToQuery` class *somewhere*, which converts a `List<FilterCondition>` to a query using `QueryBuilder`.

Should I create the `FilterConditionsToQuery` class in the Data Access Layer and directly reference it in my UI layer, or should I create a repository? What would be a better approach for an MVVM WPF application?

Comment: For this you don't need a repository.

Comment: @MikeSW, I meant "should I implement the functionality in my repository?", sorry it was ambiguous.

Comment: Still you don't need a repository :) EF does dynamic queries via LINQ. Implementing a repo means that you'll have to create your own FIlterCOnditions that need to be 'converted' into Linq. The only scenario when a repo helps you is if you don't want to be coupled to EF. But here's a lot of work and I don't know if it's worth it

Comment: @MikeSW, I am aware of that. What I meant was that the repository was going to be implemented somehow. Whether implementing it or not is not the decision that I'm trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by using the func delegate if you like to. 
first func parameter is for the where clause, second the top parameter and third for the orderby clause

program.cs

```
 var dal = new DataAccessLayer();
 var result = dal.Get(x => x.Age > 40, 5, x2 => x2.Firstname);
 //var result = dal.Get(x => x.Age > 40 && x.Firstname == "Dave", 5, x2 => x2.Firstname);
```

DataAccessLayer.cs

```
public IEnumerable<Student> Get(Func<Student, bool> expr, int top, Func<Student, object> orderBy )
{
    var list = GetStudents();
    return list.Where(expr).Take(top).OrderBy(orderBy);
}
```

Comment: But the queries are dynamically created, so somewhere I need to dynamically create the `Func`, which adds an extra layer.

Comment: how do your dynamically created queries look like? a constructed entity sql string? a dictionary?

Comment: They will be partially constructed Entity SQL strings. I will use the `ObjectQuery` class.